# LEFT JOIN with GROUP BY returns unexpected result

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, mariadb

I am trying to select all `feeheads` that do not exist in `st_annual` table using the following query, but it only returns one row while I expect to get two rows:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM hl_annual A
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT feeid, regd, class
        FROM st_annual
        GROUP BY regd, feeid
) B ON A.id = B.feeid AND A.class=B.class         
WHERE A.class='4' AND A.session='2'
AND B.feeid IS NULL
```

Please look at the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cb17). I expect to get id=3 and id=6, but I got only id=3.

I want to select all the distinct feeid present in the st_annual table and I want to compare with the id in the hl_annual table. If feeid does not exist when we group the st_table by regd and feeid, I want to get that absent fee id from hl_annual table. So from the fiddle, I get only feeid 3 which is not in st_annual, but I want to get feeid=6 also because this does not exist in one of the regd in st_annual.

Comment: Why do you need a group by at all in the subquery?  6 exists as ID 37 in your data.  why do you expect it in your results.  hl_annual and st_annual join on Id and feeId 6 exists in both data sets with hl_annual having a class of 4 (no tics should be used) and session of 2.  Since it exists in both and isn't excluded by class or session limits the feeID is not null... so 6 would be excluded.

Comment: I want to select all the distinct feeid present in the st_annual table and I want to compare with the id in the hl_annual table. If feeid does not exist when we group the st_table by regd and feeid, I want to get that absent fee id from hl_annual table. So from the fiddle, I get only feeid 3 which is not in st_annual, but I want to get feeid=6 also because this does not exist in one of the regd in st_annual.

Comment: So ID 6 is present in the st_Annual table (ID 37) (and in HL_Annual).  This means that it present in both... so it shouldn't show up. A Group by w/o an aggregate makes no sense to me.

Comment: That's why I am asking this. I have no idea at all. But in one of the regd field, ID=6 is not there.

Comment: Then your join needs to include regD as well.  So you join on class, fee and regID.  Then the check for B.feeID should work.

Comment: @xQbert, Please can you post the answer with that. I would be very happy. But in hl_annual, I don't have regd field.

Comment: Just take the subquery from the left join and make an independent query, you should be able to see the mistake in the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making a ton of assumptions....

We need a master list of class and fee's that should be present.  So first we get a distinct list from the ST_Annual table and join back to HL_Annual; but since this doesn't contain the regD for each class, we have to cross join back to get the regD for each class  Now that we have the master list, we join this back to ST_Annual to find which are missing.

```
SELECT A.*,  B.FeeID, c.regd
FROM HL_ANNUAL A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT distinct Y.class, FeeID, Z.RegD
            from ST_ANNUAL Y
            cross join (Select Distinct regD, Class from st_Annual) Z
            WHERE Y.Class = Z.Class
          ) B
  on A.ID = B.FeeID
 and A.Class = B.Class
LEFT JOIN ST_ANNUAL C
  on C.FeeID = B.FeeID
 and C.Class= B.Class
 and C.RegD = B.RegD
WHERE A.class = 4 
  AND A.session = 2
  AND C.RegD is null
Order by A.ID, A.Class
```

I can't help feeling we're missing tables related to class, regd which would make this easier particularly a table that's the relationship of class to regd and perhaps session again I'm making assumptions; for each entry.

Since I couldn't get SQL FIDDLE TO WORK... to work... http://rextester.com/SMG32021

odd that the tables already existed...  with the same data...

Oh... and The output:

```
    id  class   session feehead             amount  FeeID   regd
  1 3   4       2       Examination Fees    500     NULL    NULL
  2 6   4       2       Sports              1500    6       NULL
```

But again I caution you I had to make several assumptions about relationships between data involving class, regd and session and id/feeid... if my assumptions are wrong; then this while returning the correct results here, may not return correct results if data varies.

Comment: Empty result. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Why would use use aggregation?  Here's an idea:  use `not exists`.  Much more explicit on your intention and it should have much better performance (an index on `st_annual(fee_id, class)` helps):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM hl_annual A
WHERE A.class = 4 AND A.session = 2 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM st_annual sa
                  WHERE A.id = sa.feeid AND sa.class = B.class
                 )  ;
```

I'm not sure that this fixes the logic problem, but it is a better place to start for the problem you are asking about.

Comment: Where do you get B.class?

Comment: If you look at the fiddle, this does not solve the problem. the query in my question and your answer produces the same result.